# Cyclomatic complexity script

Tags: beginner, bash

As part of my programming training, I was told to research metrics for programming. I went ahead and turned the metrics into code starting with the cyclomatic complexity by McCabe. It works for bash sourcecode which I was targeting in this example.

My approach relies heavily on the `while read line` to read the Code line by line.
I tried to use more `Regex` at first but I soon hit a wall and decided to do it this way. Im familiar with `Regex` but inexperienced in combining them with `sed` or `awk`. So I'd like to ditch the `while read line` if that is possible for this kind of problem, and general readability tips for bash scripting would also be nice (im using vim to write the code).

```
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
    echo "Type in file name: "
    read filename
else
# $1 is the first input parameter
filename=$1
fi

counter=1
caseflag=0
casecounter=0

while read line
do

 if [ "$caseflag" == "1" ]
 then
    if [[ $line == *"#"* ]]
    then
        #takes care of the comments in the SC
        temp=${line%%#*}
        tempcounter=$(echo $temp|awk '/;;$/{counter++}END{print counter}')
        let counter=$counter+$tempcounter > /dev/null 2>&1
    else
        tempcounter=$(echo $line|awk '/;;$/{counter++}END{print counter}')
        let counter=$counter+$tempcounter > /dev/null 2>&1
    fi
 fi
#loop detection
 temp=`echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f1`
 if [ "$temp" == "until" ] || [ "$temp" == "if" ] || [ "$temp" == "else" ] || [ "$temp" == "elif" ] || [ "$temp" == "while" ] || [ "$temp" == "for" ]
 then
    let counter=$counter+1
 fi
#case detection
 if [ "$temp" == "case" ]
 then 
    caseflag=1
    let casecounter=$casecounter+1

 elif [ "$temp" == "esac" ]
 then
    caseflag=0
 fi

done < $filename

let counter=$counter-$casecounter > /dev/null 2>&1
echo "Cyclomatic complexity score: $counter"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `bash` grammar is notoriously hard to parse. Your script is easily misled by many valid `bash` constructs.

  For example, it unconditionally consider `#` as a comment, whereas it could be escaped, or a part of a special parameter `$#`, or a part of `${parameter#word}` expansion.

  It will consider the assignment (stupid but valid)

  ```
      x=\;;
  ```

  as an end of case. It will miss a loop in

  ```
      cat file | while read line
  ```

  It will count the contents of a

  ```
      <<EOF
      while
      for
      until
      EOF
  ```

  as loops.

  It incorrectly handles nested `case` statements.
- `awk` is a powerful programming language. If you feel you need to invoke it, consider using it for an entire script. It is particularly inefficient to invoke `awk` for a single line of input.
- `bash` is also a very powerful programming language. The constructs like

  ```
      temp=`echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f1`
  ```

  can be more clearly (and more efficiently) expressed in `bash`, e.g.

  ```
      read temp rest <<< $line
  ```
- Testing for the presence of `#` to remove the comment is redundant. The expansion works correctly even if it is not there (in which case the line remains unchanged).

Comment: Thx for pointing the errors out, I guess my inexperience with bash shines through. I think redoing it entirely with awk might be a nice idea. I'm going to try that. Thx for your time